# Showing both sides of a coin being flipped using Android standard animation

Tags: android, animation

I'm very close to getting a "coin flipping" animation to work, but due to the limitations (bugs?) in the current Animation system - I cannot find a way to show BOTH sides of a coin flipping in the air.

For example, I have the following Animation .XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
     android:shareInterpolator="false">    
        <scale
            android:repeatCount="17"
            android:repeatMode="reverse" 
              android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"     android:pivotY="50%"
            android:fillEnabled="true"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:duration="60"
        />      
        <scale
            android:repeatCount="1"
            android:repeatMode="reverse" 
              android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="2.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="2.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"     android:pivotY="50%"
            android:fillEnabled="true"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:duration="800"
        />      
        <translate
            android:repeatCount="1"
            android:repeatMode="reverse" 
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            android:fromXDelta="0%"
            android:toXDelta="0%"
            android:fromYDelta="0%"
            android:toYDelta="-150%"
            android:fillEnabled="true"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:duration="800" 
        />
</set>
```

This "fakes" a flipping animation by scaling the coin on the Y-axis and reversing it on a loop.  In combination to this, there's a scale to make the overall animation bigger, while also translating it up and down.  But it is only ever gonna show the one side of the coin.

I tried having two of these animations, each side of the coin, running at the same time, but I cannot find a way to stagger them due to the REPEATCOUNT not working when applied to an AnimationSet.  Otherwise I could introduce some kind of delay after one anim (and before the other one) so they alternate, giving the illusion of a coin flipping.

Does anyone know any way I can tweak this to get the desired result?

I had thought of giving up and doing a frame-based anim (pre-render the flip as frames), but it appears you can't mix Frame & Tween anims, so I'd lose the flip "height" and "distance" effects.

(I have another issue when it comes to the coin landing - e.g. the final result is random, but I'm hoping I can switch in the actual result at the end?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows the same procedure
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

Comment: Thanks for that Jaydeep.  I had come across that article before, but it seemed a bit overkill for what I wanted to do.  Plus, I wasn't sure how I could also combine it with the other effects (Zoom and Move). However, it's looking like it's the only real way to do it...

Answer (score 4):

I recently wanted to implement something like this for a project. I finally came up with a solution and the result was good enough. Hope it helps someone else who is trying to achieve the same animation.

I uploaded the result as a [gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Thanasis1101/3ed8ac2a132606801c2c85624c603627).

For a preview of the animation [click here](https://github.com/TeamLS/CoinToss/blob/master/ezgif-6-6b939ea6bd.gif).

For the full android studio project visit our [CoinToss](https://github.com/TeamLS/CoinToss) repository.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something like this myself, even with the scaling of the image so it appears the imageview is getting closer to the screen.

I combined your animation with this solution to do exactly what you wanted and its fairly lightweight, missing out the need for multiple views.

https://github.com/Lojko/Booty/blob/master/src/game/booty/BootyGameActivity.java

Changed Location of the Original Link: http://www.jasoncavett.com/2011/05/changing-images-during-an-android-animation/#comments

See the FlipCoin class and how its used, I have an animation already existing (created in the same way as detailed by the link)

Comment: the link you mentioned in the answer is dead.

Comment: I have the code lying around on GitHub, I'll update the post with a link to it ASAP.

Comment: I found the changed webpage of the original link, if anyone happens to be interested in the future!